# Partial derivatives of $f(x,y) = \frac{|x|^3 + |y|^2}{|x|+|y|}$ and $f(0,0)=0$

Tags: partial-derivative

How to prove, that the partial derivatives of the expression $f(x,y) = \frac{|x|^3 + |y|^2}{|x|+|y|}$ at $(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$ exist and how to determine their value in $f(0,0)$?

Comment: Did you mean partial derivatives at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Yes in $(0,0)$, thanks for the remark!

Comment: Are you also sure that all the partial derivatives exist?

Comment: I'm not sure, thats why I want to know if they exist, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_{x}(0,0)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x,0)|_{x=0}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{|x|^3}{|x|}|_{x=0}=2x|_{x=0}=0$$

$$f_{y}(0,0)=\frac{d}{dy}f(0,y)|_{y=0}=\frac{d}{dy}\frac{|y|^2}{|y|}|_{y=0}=\frac{d}{dy}|y||_{y=0}$$

Obviously the $y$-partial derivative for $f$ at $(0,0)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi(y) = f(0,y)$, then we see that $\phi(y) = |y|$, which is not differentiable at $y = 0$. Hence the partial of $f$ with respect to $y$ does not exist at $y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance. Using the definition, we have

> $$f_x(0,0) =\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(0+h,0) -f(0,0)}{h} =\dots\,.$$

You need the definition of the absolute value to finish the problem, since you need to find $\lim_{h\to 0^-}$ and $\lim_{h\to 0^+}$. Do the same for the other partial derivative with respect to $y$.